# Reviewing a pending edit from within the first post queue changes review type

Tags: support, bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

I just came across a review for first posts with a pending edit in it. I approved the edit and was planning to read further. However, the system seems to assume that `I am done`, and automatically redirected me to the Suggested Edits review queue, which is a different review queue.

Am I hallucinating or is this a bug?  Has anyone else had a similar experience?

Comment: Just happened again.