# Review first posts: upvoting a comment gives "I am done" option

Tags: support, review-queues

Related: [Reviewing a pending edit from within the first post queue changes review type](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311620/reviewing-a-pending-edit-from-within-the-first-post-queue-changes-review-type)

If you upvote a comment on the question while reviewing first posts, you are no longer able to choose "No action is needed" and are instead given the "I am done" option. I do not know if this actually matters; perhaps the two options are more or less the same, but I am putting it out here just in case it is a bug.

**Edit:** The comment by Jeffrey Bosboom explained it well:

> Action was needed (commenting), but someone already left the comment you would have added, so you upvoted it. If that's all that was necessary, you're done.

Comment: You can't say "No action is needed" because you just took an action.

Comment: Action was needed (commenting), but someone already left the comment you would have added, so you upvoted it.  If that's all that was necessary, you're done.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bug.

I agree the two buttons are similar, but they aren't the same.

In First Posts, any action you take like voting, editing, etc is counted as an action. Here is when to use what:

- No Action Needed: This has to be used when the post you're reviewing is perfect, and does not need any action to be taken.
- I'm Done: This button can be clicked only when you've done some action on the post. You use this when whatever you think should be done on the post is done, and your job on the post is over. Using this doesn't mean that the post is perfect. As even flagging is an action, and means that the post is wrong.

The "I'm Done" button can be also thought as two buttons fitted into one:

- I've done my actions, and the post is now correct.
- I've done my actions but this post is still wrong (flagging).

These buttons are merged into one (analogy).

Comment: perfect? no, perfectly neutral, a perfect post really deserves at least an upvote.

Comment: Well not always @Deduplicator. If you know about the topic the question is asking, and think the question is perfect, upvote it. If the question looks perfect, properly formatted, gives proper code, reasons, what all he /she has tried, but if you still don't know about the topic, you shouldn't vote on it, either way. This will mislead answerers, and is wrong. It is possible that the post looks perfect, but the error had been caused by a simple typographical error. Thus voting on something which you don't know is wrong.