# How was I to tell that this answer was a duplicate when confronted with it as an audit?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16857248) and had my review rights suspended.

I think this was an unfair audit. The answer I was reviewing looked OK, so I clicked "No action needed". It then turned out that the answer had 1 downvote for duplicating an existing answer.

This is the second time I have failed an audit for exactly the same reason. I don't think the audits or the suspension were fair in this case.

Yes, there was a comment on the answer that clearly stated it was a duplicate, but [**comments are not shown for audits**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) (post details are faked, including the score, user, and comments). They only become visible *after* the review, so I had no way of knowing that it was a duplicate.

The answer's author listed several possibilities for the issue in question, and provided steps to fix it. The answer was, by all measures visible to me, correct. Its only problem was that it duplicated an existing answer, but I couldn't have known this at the time of the review.

Opening the question to see the details of the reviewed item kinda defeats the purpose of doing audits (downvote if you see downvotes, upvote if you see upvotes).

Is there a way to appeal the failed audit when I'm sure that I didn't make a mistake? No automatic system is perfect, and there should be a way to appeal if it made a wrong decision.

---

The "possible duplicates" do not answer my question.

[Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly) answers the question, *"Why I was banned from reviews"*, but I already know the answer to that question: I was banned because the system deemed it necessary to take action, whereas I clicked "No action needed".

However, my question is, *how do I appeal the automatic ban when I believe that my action was correct, based on the information provided in the review queue?*

Comment: You could post the audit link here with your reasons as to why you think your response is correct.. Without that information, this looks like a rant..

Comment: @gnat - My question is different. Your link answers why I was banned, and I know why. My question is how to appeal after automatic ban of imperfect system.

Comment: @suraj Edited the original question

Comment: there are some cases when appeal makes sense but your doesn't look like that. Ban is totally deserved, use the time off reviews to learn how to do it right, the way explained in duplicate answer. Now that you posted link it is apparent that your review was very wrong. Answer has comment pointing that this duplicates prior one and provided link. All you needed was to read that comment and click the link to check if this is indeed so. You didn't do that and marked outright [meta-tag:plagiarism] as "No Action Needed", this is blatant abuse of review

Comment: @gnat "Answer has comment pointing that this duplicates prior one and provided link" - that's the whole point - comments are not shown in First Answer reviews.

Comment: @gnat I think you missed the line _In "First answer" or "Late answer" audits comments are not shown until after the review,_ .. So OP would have to go to the actual question where it wouldnt be shown as he cannot see deleted posts

Comment: Umm…I'm pretty sure that audits show you the comments on the answer ([this question provides confirmation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319773/366904)) and there was a comment there (been there since July 11th; you got the audit less than an hour ago) indicating that the answer had been plagiarized. If you didn't read the comments, then you deserve to have failed the audit!

Comment: *"and I couldn't know it at the time of the review."* -> You didn't know because you didn't bother to check that. It's your job as a reviewer to do that and you failed to do your job properly. Thus the review ban is correct.

Comment: @suraj I regularly do FP and LA reviews and all comments are always there, including audits

Comment: ok.. Then I stand corrected.. That means this is a genuinely failed audit

Comment: @gnat Well, now I obviously can't check that, but it says so even in the comment to the answer in the link you provided

Comment: ...I usually complement my rants about careless reviews pointing that in case if doing it right seems like too much work [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601) but in this case it isn't needed. Gee all what is needed was just to read comment, click the link and check few first words of prior answer that was copied, that's just a matted of few seconds

Comment: @gnat See edited question. And opening the reviewed question to see what review should be "right" defeats the purpose to do audits at all.

Comment: @gnat In general: yes, reviews show comments. But audits don't

Comment: @CodyGray, Took me 30min to verify but Audit **Do not** show comments. Just got one.

Comment: @CodyGray "this question provides confirmation" - that question doesn't make any mention of audits whatsoever.

Comment: I already saw Drag and Drop's comment. I don't have a "super-reopen" power. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Not yet anyway ;)

Comment: *And opening the reviewed question to see what review should be "right" defeats the purpose to do audits at all.* No, it doesn't. The purpose of audits is to force users to slow down and pay attention. Opening the actual question post so you can see all the available information means that you're slowing down and paying attention. If you're opening posts to check for comments and plagiarism then the audits are working.

Comment: It does, because doing that would allow me to make review decisions based solely on the number of upvotes/downvotes next to the reviewed item.

Comment: @BSMP There's a reason audits fake post information, like comments or number of votes - it is to review the item itself based on its quality, not just look at what others have done and do the same.

Comment: Lets go back to the topic, First I agree this audit can feel like a trap. But this answer really need edit it's almost not readable because of the lack of formating. 2nd, It's hard for me to believe than you were ban because of this review. I mean there must be other failed audit. In the Audit that you fail one was a bad one, ok.. but all the other fail show you should be more attentive in your review.

Comment: Nobody gets suspended for one audit - yes, I have failed another audit and the other one was fair. But what I am complaining about is this particular audit, which I feel was unjust, and I'm asking if there is a way to appeal if you feel the audit was not right.

Comment: If you don't want to just do what other users have done then don't. No one has suggested that you have to. But it is not cheating the audit to get more information than exists in the review queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consensus here is that you are expected to click through to the original question to check the answer against other answers, particularly for first post answers and late answers. I frequently do that now, having gone through the same shock and pain you are going through now, and I now frequently come across late answers that have the exact same info as other upvoted/accepted answers. When found, I add a comment to the answer indicating it as duplicate and apply a custom flag explaining it. Otherwise, as you have found, they are easy to miss when going through the queue.

That practice is a good one for the reasons I described. However, the review process should be improved. You are right that you do not see things like that from the review window and the audits that get you seem unfair, and I will agree with you on that. You will probably not get the ban overturned, because you did come up with a wrong conclusion.

If it is any solace to you, even though it is a bitter pill to swallow, you are not alone in learning this lesson the hard way.

Comment: Can you clarify this answer - in particular how to close it as duplicate with special flag? It seems there is more focus on the ppl failing audit due to this than to actually explain how to review the answers.
I got a similar duplicate answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680305/listjsonobject-vs-jsonarray  - I could not figure out the best way to close it.