# Why did I fail this late answer audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/23281765) recommends an operator to solve the problem. Maybe it poorly answers the question, but one cannot see the question in the late answers queue (never mind, you can). I've seen many high scoring answers that are very short and recommend a single function.

Comment: If in doubt use the [skip] button or open the question in another window and take a closer look.

Comment: The late answers queue is different than the low quality posts queue. There is more expected of you in the late answers queue, like making sure it isn't a duplicate answer, voting, and suggesting improvements where applicable. While that answer arguably may be an acceptable attempt to answer the problem, it definitely doesn't qualify for "No Action Needed". A downvote and a request for improvement are both actions that are needed.

Comment: this is also a link only answer / recommending a function without any examples whatsoever

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre according to the apples analogy post the mention of a method name is sufficient even without examples of usage.

Comment: sufficient for a downvote perhaps :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I’ve seen many answers which name just the required function and are not deleted nor are they edited

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre my point being that it doesn't qualify as a link-only answer, or a Not an Answer flag.

Comment: depends how easy it is to use the function. Let's see some answers to this meta post.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre As a reviewer, how am I supposed to know how easy it is to use the function in an area I have no experience in? The only thing I can judge is whether there is an attempt to answer the question

Comment: don't ask me, I would have voted to delete :) Tiny Giant has a point: this is a new answer on old question. The quality expectations are high on those ones. So short answers with link like those are considered bad.

Comment: note that Bhargav has converted the answer to a comment. Which is a good call as the information remains in a comment. The best way would be to edit to show an example of the function in action.

Comment: Tiny Giant's general point about the difference between the Low Quality Posts and Late Answers queues is highly relevant. Still, I can see myself failing this audit even while accounting for that. The action I'd be inclined to take would be leaving a comment suggesting the author should add an example to the answer. However, someone else had already left such a comment, so I wouldn't have added a redundant one. It appears [upvoting that comment would pass the audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319773), though I find it a little odd that such an insubstantial action can make a difference.

Comment: If you gave no experience in that area and feel you can’t judge the answer appropriately; it’s always better to skip and leave to other users.

Comment: You probable already know about [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts), but it is always a relevant link for these questions.

Answer (score 5):

The late answers queue is different than the low quality posts queue. There is more expected of you in the late answers queue, like making sure it isn't a duplicate answer, voting, and suggesting improvements where applicable:

> **No Action Needed** when this post needs no action from you.
>
> **I'm Done** is only available if you've done one of the following:
>
> - **Vote up or down** to rate the answer's helpfulness
> - **Edit** to improve the answer's appearance, clarity, or accuracy
> - **Comment** to leave constructive feedback for the author, or vote up 
>     existing comments
> - **Flag** to notify the moderators of serious problems
>
> Be sure to **leave a comment** if you can help the user out, or click **Skip**
>   if you are not sure and want to go to the next item.

While that answer arguably may be an acceptable attempt at answering the problem, it definitely doesn't qualify for "No Action Needed".

Minimally you could have:

- downvoted the answer for lack of usefulness,
- posted a comment requesting improvement, and
- upvoted the existing comment that pointed out a deficiency with the answer

Technically in this case upvoting the existing comment would be incorrect as this post is not a link only answer, so the comment below the answer was not correct:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

The link isn't the answer to the question, the name of the method is the answer to the question and the link is for further information regarding the method.

A more appropriate comment would be:

> While this may be an adequate attempt to answer the question, it could benefit from further information regarding the usage of the mentioned method and how it could solve the problem posed in the question. Short answers that lack explanation may be downvoted and deleted by the community.

Furthermore, contrary to your assertion that the question is not shown in the late answers review queue, it is in fact shown below the question, as well as you are shown how many other answers are on the question.

All of this to say that choosing "No Action Needed" was not warranted and there is much more that you could and should have done.

If you feel that you are not capable of adequately assessing the quality and usefulness of a given answer due to a lack of experience in the target technology, you can skip individual questions and you can filter by tag if you want to focus on a specific tag or set of tags.

---

**Further reading:**

- [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)