# Why did I miss this audit? (late answers)

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

I just got review banned for missing [this audit question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/23281791).
The comments on the answer say to "include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference" - which they did. Unless I'm missing something, this should have been a "No action needed." I'll take the ban, I just want to know why my response was not appropriate.

[image: Audit fail]

Comment: The answer [that I just wrote for another question about a failed late answer audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386106/4639281) is equally applicable to this audit. For one you could have edited to improve the horrible formatting. You could have then posted a comment requesting that they explain how the quote applies to the question asked. The purpose of the late answer queue is not to review the comments posted under the answer that you're reviewing, the point is to review the answer itself. Regardless "No Action Needed" definitely does not apply here.

Comment: @TinyGiant thanks. This is what I get for not paying close enough attention/using the skip button